# What is a better way to say 'beliefs and way of life' in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, american-english

> The Vietnam War was a tragic time. There were countless casualties,
>   which could have been prevented. But does that automatically
>   immaterialize the **way of life** for a person? Muhammad Ali didn’t think
>   so.

This is what I wrote for my English paper on Muhammad Ali. Does anyone have a better way to say 'beliefs and way of life' in a single word?

Comment: The best way to say "beliefs and way of life" is "beliefs and way of life".  The longer, slightly redundant phrase better emphasizes the concept than would some shorter one.

Comment: Jess, please look up the meaning of *immaterialize*, think about the relationship between your first two sentences and the question that follows, and then consider rewording your question.

Comment: Creed?  a set of beliefs or aims that guide someone's actions.
"liberalism was more than a political creed"

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to believe this is an English word, but the word **weltanschauung** (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weltanschauung) suits your purposes nicely.

Answer (score 1):

*Values*

You can talk about a person's *values*.

Technically I suppose "values" are just *moral beliefs* or *principles*, but I think we can all agree Muhammad Ali lived according to his values, so in the context I think *values* expresses your idea.

I have no idea what *immaterialize* is supposed to mean, though.